# VirtualBoxの共有フォルダの設定について

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian

VirtualBoxにLinuxをインストールして、ホストとゲスト間で共有フォルダを作りたいです。
GuestAddtionsをインストール、VirtualBoxマネージャーから共有フォルダを追加して、自動マウントと永続化にチェックを入れましたが、ゲスト側から見れません。
ホストOSはWindows
ゲストOSはdebian
です。何か足りない手順がありますか?
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mount -t vboxsf 共有フォルダ名 マウント先ディレクトリ名
を試してみてください。